# How to compare datetime with 10 minutes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to check if the `datetime now - datetime given = 10 minutes`

Below is my code: 
`var duration = Date.now() - customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime.getTime()`;

and then I compare it with 10 minutes in millisecs:

```
    var TEN_MINUTES = 10*60*1000;

    if(duration > TEN_MINUTES){
            //do smtg
    }
```

But this thing always returns true because I checked TEN_MINUTES in UTC, it is equals to `Thu Jan 01 1970 00:10:00`.

I would like to know how can I check if the duration is more than 10 minutes ?

Comment: Why you checked TEN_MINUTES in UTC? duration is just a long int with millisecond value. You just need to minus two date's timestamp to get the millisecond difference. And just compare it to the TEN_MINUTES value.

Comment: even if i dont check it in UTC, the if condition is always true even though it is not true.@TerryWei

Comment: is customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime.getTime() in timestamp format too like Date.now() ?

Comment: @FewFlyBy yup correct

Comment: OK, you just need to get the long value to compare to the other long value. Don't try to change the long value to date or other thing

Comment: just debug by checking duration's value and comparing it to expected result. duration should be in milliseconds.

Comment: First you need to check the type of duration is really number value. Second you can use if(duration - TEN_MINUTES > 0) condition. If there's still wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

```
var TEN_MINUTES = 10*60*1000;
var duration = Date.now() - customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime.getTime();
if (duration > TEN_MINUTES) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Not sure where you went wrong since it sounds like you got 90% of the way there on your own, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

How about `Math.abs(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime())/1000` ?

Comment: `Math.abs` makes no sense here, the supplied Date should not be later than `Date.now()` and if it is that should fail an assertion.